# Flutter - Issue when i generate code with build runner

Tags: flutter, dart

When i perform build runner i have an issue
I am tryin' to use GetIt with code generator and dependency injection

The error message:
[image]

Code in pubspec.yaml

`#dependency injection   injectable: ^1.5.0   get_it: ^7.2.0` 
``dev_dependencies: flutter_test: sdk: flutter`

`flutter_lints: ^2.0.0`
`build_runner: ^2.1.5`
`injectable_generator: ^1.5.3`
`` ` ``

My code in injection.dart
`` `import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart'; ``
`import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';`

`final getIt = GetIt.instance;`

`@InjectableInit()`
`void configureDependencies() => $initGetIt(getIt);`
`` ` ``

I need to know if this issue is about packages, its version or my code

Comment: try run * flutter pub cache clean
* flutter clean
* flutter pub cache repair
* flutter pub get

Comment: Thanks Rahul!, i did it and the same error message is shown.... [SEVERE] injectable_generator:injectable_config_builder on lib/injection.dart:

Stack Overflow

Comment: I am not sure about this issues.